# Generating Key Pair Authentication with passphrase for Snowflake

Tags: openssl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a public and private key for Snowflakes RSA authentication. I;ve been following [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html#configuring-key-pair-authentication) documentation. However, I need for there to be a passphrase and the example provided does not elucidate such a feature.

This is what I've tried, but it does not work:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out -passout pass:THISwillBeYOURpass rsa_key.p8
```

I'm pretty sure I have the wrong syntax but after reading openssl documentation, it seems like that is the way to do it...

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
........................................................................................+++
.........................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter Encryption Password:
```

Enter a password for the encryption and that should do it.